# Spring boot logger interceptor remove form-data from request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Have a problem with my spring boot application, i want to log all request and reponse, for do that i implement this logic:

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        CachedHttpServletRequest cachedHttpServletRequest = new CachedHttpServletRequest(request);
        String body = IOUtils.toString(cachedHttpServletRequest.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        LOGGER.info(" Body: " + body);
        filterChain.doFilter(cachedHttpServletRequest, responseWrapper);
        LOGGER.info("Response :" + new String(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray()));

        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
```

```
public class CachedHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private final byte[] cachedPayload;
    
    public CachedHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        InputStream requestInputStream = request.getInputStream();
        this.cachedPayload = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(requestInputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
        return new CachedServletInputStream(this.cachedPayload);
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() {
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.cachedPayload);
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(byteArrayInputStream));
    }
}
```

```
public class CachedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CachedServletInputStream.class);

    private final InputStream cachedInputStream;

    public CachedServletInputStream(byte[] cachedBody) {
        this.cachedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedBody);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFinished() {
        try {
            return cachedInputStream.available() == 0;
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return cachedInputStream.read();
    }
}
```

This code work fine for nomal request, but i have problem with endpoint like this:

```
  @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, value = "/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> uploadFile(
            @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
            @RequestPart("body") BodyDTO bodyDTO
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(myService.uploadFile(multipartFile, bodyDTO));
    }
```

Becuase i receive this error `2023-11-13T01:26:36.434+01:00  INFO 58866 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] c.s.o.exception.ErrorHandler             : Required part 'file' is not present.`

If i remove the log interceptor, the response it's ok, no error about bad request missing file, i think my `CachedHttpServletRequest` remove the `@RequestPart`, can you help me? How can bypass this problem?

I take the code from follwing guide:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

Thank you

Comment: Spring already provides request/response logging. Instead of reinventing your own, use that filter instead. Include the `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` enable debug and see them being logged. No need to write your own. If you really want to write your own at least re-use the `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` and `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` which already implement (properly) the re-use of the `InputStream` and friends.

Comment: I want write my own interceptor for different reason, i try to use ContentCachingRequestWrapper, but the problem persist

Comment: You used it how? As classes as is or as base classes to extend from? Also why write your own? What are your different reasons to not use an out-of-the-box solution?

Comment: I try to use instead CachedHttpServletRequest ContentCachingRequestWrapper, but never change, should I do anything else? Could you give an example in this case? I need to make my own custom interceptor, because I have some requirements that I have to meet, so I need my own custom solution.

Comment: It is not an interceptor I hope but rather a filter. If this is an interceptor it simply won't work as you cannot replace the request and resonse.

Comment: sorry, it's a filter I linked the guide I used to implement it, you can consult it here  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

Comment: Still I wonder why you need your own implementation instead something out-of-the-box. If this breaks stuff down the line there must be something else that is interfering as well.

Comment: I have several requirements to make my custom implementation, let's say that this is my service on which I have to do some analysis on requests and responses, so I need to read the requests and responses on my filters and manipulate them in different ways, via product logs on file for example or by saving to an in-memory database, so I need to be able to access all my requests and responses on my filter

Comment: Which is why you can plugin various appenders into your logging frameworks to do just that, so you don't need to burden your application with that logic. But nonetheless I would expect the spring provided wrappers to work if you use them correctly (I see you use the response one so wondering why you aren't using the request one).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution this is the final code:

```
@Component
public class LogFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LogInterceptor1.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = requestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = responseWrapper(response);

        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);

        logRequest(requestWrapper);
        logResponse(responseWrapper);
    }

    private void logRequest(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request) {
        log.info("Body: " +  new String(request.getContentAsByteArray()));
    }

    private void logResponse(ContentCachingResponseWrapper response) throws IOException {
        log.info("Response: " + new String(response.getContentAsByteArray()));
      response.copyBodyToResponse();
    }

    private ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper(ServletRequest request) {
        if (request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper) {
            return requestWrapper;
        }
        return new ContentCachingRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
    }

    private ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper(ServletResponse response) {
        if (response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper) {
            return responseWrapper;
        }
        return new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
    }
}
```

Following https://vkuzel.com/log-requests-and-responses-including-body-in-spring-boot

Thank you all.